# Efficient data structure for finding non-overlapping range containing a number

Tags: c++, search, data-structures, range

a data structure to store the start and endpoint of a range.

```
rangename      start     end

range1          10        11

range2          20        22

range3          0         5
```

now if i have to find the range in which a number 'x' may exist.

What would be the efficient way of storing this in c++ ?

I'm trying to use map. but then search to find the range might be expensive ( which i'm not sure of). Suggest a good data structure.

*I should be able to find whether the element is present in a range or not. The ranges should not be mix and matched and no adjacent or other bounds.*

If I need to a find an element 3, it is present in range 3, But an element 12 is not present at all. Just looping through cannot be an efficient way.

Comment: Do your ranges overlap?  Does finding the range for any particular number result in a unique answer?

Comment: How many ranges will you have? How often will they change? How large is the total population of values (i.e. max-min)?

Comment: Sorry for the error in the question. The ranges will not overlap( I was under the impression it may.)

And the population of values are a hundred to 200 records at the maximum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I have changed this answer since the asker clarified that his ranges do not overlap.)

If the set of ranges does not change, you can use a sorted vector and binary search, as suggested in ravenspoint's answer.

If the set of ranges changes over time, you might still use a sorted vector, or you might want to use a `std::map`.  You need to try both and see which one is faster in that case.

Comment: I still find problems with actually finding whether an element is present in a range. The problem is it should be found either its present in anyone of the range strictly or not?! No mix and matching the ranges.

Answer (score 2):

`vector< pair< int>>` stored sorted so you can binary search perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ranges do not overlap:

Store each range in a simple structure

```
range {
  int low;
  int high;
  string name;
}
```

Store the ranges in a sorted vector, by low.

Find required range using binary search for largest low less than target.

Comment: His range1 and range3 examples overlap.

Comment: Apparently they do not overlap.  The question is confusing.  I have edited question so example does not overlap

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the question. You have edited before I could. I dint notice the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

just dump all the values , starting and ending into a vector or array, and then sort it. since the ranges dont overlap, once the array is sorted, you will have start, stop,start,stop,etc.. then, you could use a binary search to find the index of the vector. then its just a question of whether its odd or even

assuming, you are getting the ranges from the stream

```
vector<int> ranges;
int n;
while(in >> n){
    ranges.push_back(n);
}
sort(ranges.begin(),ranges.end())

int x;
cout <<"please enter a value to search for: ";
cin >> x;
int index = binary_search(x,ranges);

if(index % 2){
    cout << "The value " << x << "is in the range of "
         << ranges[index-1] << " to " <<       ranges[index] << endl;
}else{
    if(ranges[index] == x){
         cout << "The value " << x << "is in the range of "
              << ranges[index] << " to " <<       ranges[index+1] << endl;
    }
    else{
         cout << "Value " << x << " is not in any range\n";
    }
 }
```

where binary search would be defined as

```
 int binary_search(int x, vector<int>& vec, int s = 0; int f = -1){
     if(f == -1)f=vec.size();
     if(s >= f) return s;
     int n = (f-s)/2 + s;
     if(vec[n] == x)return n;
     if(vec[n] < x)return binary_search(x,vec,s,n-1);
     return binary_search(x,vec,n+1,f);
 }
```

hopefully I didn't screw up the binary search, but it is designed in such a way, that if the value is not found, the index of the next largest value is returned.

Comment: I need to find whether the element is present in a range and it should not mix and matched and it should be strictly either present or not.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a B+ tree?
With B+ tree, the fan-out would be small and search would be fast too.